# Can only reference properties of a sub-object if the sub-object is embedded

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus

I would like to retrieve data by the parent key with datanucleus on Google AppEngine. I use JPA.

Here is my Stock bean (the parent):

```
@Entity
public class Stock implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="stock")
    private List<StockValue> stockValues;
}
```

Here is my StockValue bean (the children):

```
@Entity
public class StockValue implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @ManyToOne
    private Stock stock;
}
```

I tried to do my request like this (Query is datanucleus Query):

```
DatastoreService datastoreService = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Query queryStock = new Query("Stock");
queryStock.addFilter("name", FilterOperator.EQUAL, "toto");

PreparedQuery prepare = datastoreService.prepare(queryStock);
Entity asSingleEntity = prepare.asSingleEntity();

Query query = Query("StockValue", asSingleEntity.getKey());
prepare = datastoreService.prepare(query);

List<Entity> asList = prepare.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(10));
```

And all work fine with that. But I get Entities and I would prefer to work with my beans. So I tried to do this (Query is javax Query):

```
Query createQuery = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Stock p WHERE p.name = \"toto\"");
Object singleResult = createQuery.getSingleResult();
Stock stockEntity = (Stock)singleResult;

createQuery = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM StockValue p WHERE p.key IS NOT null AND p.key.parentKey = :parentKey ");
createQuery.setParameter(":parentKey", stockEntity.getKey());
Object singleResult2 = createQuery.getSingleResult();
```

And here is my problem, I get this error:

```
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.FatalNucleusUserException: SELECT FROM StockValue p WHERE p.key IS NOT null AND p.key.parentKey = :parentKey: Can only reference properties of a sub-object if the sub-object is embedded.
```

I don't understand this. My relationship between beans seems good because if I do this:

```
stockEntity.getStockValues();
```

I get stockValues correctly. 
Why does my request fail ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell: in GAE you can only query within one entity kind, or in JPA/JDO parlance, within one class. Since `StockValue` and `Stock` are two separate classes and hence two separate entity kinds, you can not query across them.

As error suggests: you could query if you [embedded one classes into another](http://bpossolo.blogspot.com/2012/01/jpa-embedded-classes-on-app-engine.html) via @Embedded annotation. In this case you'd have two classes but only one entity kind in datastore.

Also: [`key.parentKey`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key#getParent%28%29) has nothing to do with entity relationships. "Parent" is a concept in GAE Datastore used to define [Entity Groups](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions#Entity_Groups), which are used to define the scope of transactions.

Comment: Ok I understand the problem. Have you an idea how can I get my children from my parent to have beans and no entities ?